# Lambda function to write into S3 - IAM policy to access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Here is my policy which grants read/write access still not able to write into S3 bucket

**Problem**

Still getting below error:

> Failed to upload /tmp/test.txt to bucketname/Automation_Result_2019-07-09 04:20:32_.csv: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

**Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ConsoleAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MYBUCKETPOLICY",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Python code (within Lambda function)**
Relevant part of code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

target_bucket = 'bucket-name'
target_file = "Output/Automation_Result_"+EST+"_.txt"

s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/test.txt', target_bucket, target_file, ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId":"XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX" })
```

This is how my bucket public access looks like!

[image: This is how my bucket public access looks like..]

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me!

I took your policy, renamed the bucket and attached it to a user as their only policy.

I was then able to **successfully** copy an object to and from the bucket.

If it is not working for you, then either you are not using the credentials that are associated with this policy, or there is another policy that is preventing the access, such as a **Deny** policy or a scope-limiting policy.

Comment: Albeit using appropriate role, I am still getting "Access Denied" error. I suspect bucket policy to be the culprit, please have a look at my question [modified question]

Comment: It's just a matter of few seconds, Please check now.. updated my bucket policy.

Comment: Ah! `PutObject` will be denied if KMS encryption is not specified. When you are uploading the object, are you specifying encryption? Can you update the question to show how you are uploading the file?

Comment: Updated my file_upload method, bucket public access setting as well.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but take a look at how `SSEKMSKeyId` is supplied in the code example on: [Tutorial: AWS KMS S3 replication](https://blog.davincisoftware.sk/aws-kms-s3-replication). It uses a full ARN. Worth trying!